# How do I deselect a tool in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, tools

I've finished rotating, and now wish to move the handheld eyedropper under the eye. So I'm trying to deselect the Rotate Tool.   If I click on the image, the Rotate box reappears, undesiredly. If I click anywhere else, nothing happens.

The Select > None tool is unavailable and greyed.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scott is correct. There is no way to have no tool selected.  This is the same in GIMP and other raster image editors like Photoshop.  Also, *Select > None* simply deselects a selection. It has nothing to do with the tools.

I think the main problem I see with your screen shot is that you have a "Floating Selection" active.  GIMP is different from Photoshop in this respect, and this behaviour can confuse people who've only used Photoshop.

So, now all you need to do now is to decide what to do with the Floating Selection.

**Either:** attach it to the existing layer by hitting the Anchor icon in the layers panel.  But this will attach it back to the image layer, and that probably isn't what you want.

**Or:** hit the New Layer icon in the layers panel, to anchor the Floating Selection to a layer of its own. Then you can use the Move Tool, to move the image where you like.

Answer (score 3):

In **most** applications, my experience would tell me to *select another tool*.

I'm not a Gimp user, but from what I know about software, there's no possibility of having *no tool selected*.

In all the software I've used you **must** have a tool selected at all times. If you no longer wish to use the Rotate tool, select another tool. It is my understanding that the *default* tool in Gimp is the Selection Tool. So merely click that in the toolbar.

The Select > None in all likelihood refers to selections *within the image*, not the tools.

Comment: That is definitely want it refers to. Also maybe add the the default "non tool" would just be the selection tool.

Comment: would there be an apply button not visible somewhere? I see the layer selected is floating selection. One might believe that an action has to be confirmed before things return to normal.

Answer (score -2):

In Photoshop, control-D will remove the selection. This is my problem too in GIMP, selecting another area only means I get the same selection back.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Unfortunately, this doesn't answer the question asked which is how to deselect a tool, not how to remove a selection.

Comment: you're looking for ctrl+shift+a in gimp